# BadTokenException in Asynctask progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm new to android,this maybe simple question but i cant able to find the answer for it,i'm using tabactivity while changing the activities the bottom tab's are missing so i 
used below code to hold the tab by changing the view,so it works fine

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Actually my problem is i want to select something from 2nd activity to 1st ActivityGroup,in the 2nd activity i have one button called done

Here is my 2nd activity

```
public class Woosuite_Twiter_Feed_list extends Activity implements
    OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.woosuite_twitlist);

    Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Woosuite_Feed.class);
            i.setClass(getParent(), Woosuite_Feed.class);
            Woosuite_Feed feed = (Woosuite_Feed) getParent();
            feed.replaceContentView("one", i);      
        }
    });
```

while clicking done button in 2nd activity then first activitygroup asyncTask class is called,in that i'm getting

> Android: “BadTokenException: Unable to add window; is your activity running?
>   i dont know how to solve this,please provide some solution.

here is my 1st ActivityGroup oncreate

```
     public class  Woosuite_Feed extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener
    {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.woosuite_feed);
        LinkedFeeds feeds = new LinkedFeeds();
        feeds.execute("");
}
```

Here is my 1st ActivityGroup AsyncTask

```
public class LinkedFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!isFinishing()){
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Woosuite_Feed.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();  
        }
        super.onPreExecute();
    }       
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: is asynctask an inner class of activity class

Comment: try this Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Woosuite_Feed.class);

Comment: No, inner class of activitygroup ,that is 1st one(ActivityGroup)